# What is the most appropriate way to deal with a wrong answer that has been accepted?

Tags: discussion, answering-questions, moderation

For example, the asker of this question about wallpaper resolutions: [What is the default resolution of a wallpaper that fits the homescreen exactly in an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper) marked the first answer that was posted as correct.  The answer is not correct.  In this case what's the most appropriate way to correct this?

I just added the correct answer and left a couple comments.  I didn't down vote it because I wanted to give the author of the answer the opportunity to correct his answer.  Thoughts?

Comment: Go ahead and downvote if the answer is wrong -- but try to leave a reason why you're downvoting. I hate drive-by downvotes. Plus, you can change your vote if the author changes the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Treat it like any other answer. Leave a comment about the error to urge the author to correct it and to alert others.

There's a common fallacy about the "accepted answer;" that its means it was selected as the "right" answer or the "best" answer. Accepted answer means only that it was the post that *best* helped the author of the question. Nothing more. It's unfortunate that the answer happened to be incorrect (easily remedied as I described above) but there's nothing to be done about changing the author's personal choice.